# Test android app with api diffrent than available on device

Tags: android, android-sdk-1.6

I want to ensure that my app is compatible with api ver. 4 ( android 1.6). Is it enough to set build target on my IDE at ver. 4? I don't have device with such low api.

Comment: a) Emulator b)cyanogenmod or similar

Comment: `I want to ensure that my app is compatible with api ver. 4 ( android 1.6)` - what for? I do not think bothering all those 3 people worldwide with android 1.6 makes any sense. They are most likely dead anyway :)

Comment: Client requirements ...

Answer (score -1):

Check the version share of android to make an intelligent decision:~

[Android Dashboards](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

And then you can use the simulator to test your application or flash with the wanted ROM like it has been advised.